# How to change date-format while binding date in ng-model through md-datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

```html
<md-input-container>
  <label>Planned Date</label>
  <md-datepicker
     ng-model="editVersionCtrl.selectedPlannedDate"
     ng-change="editVersionCtrl.checkPlannedDate()">
  </md-datepicker>
</md-input-container>
```

I have a date which I'm binding from backend in ng-model. It's appearing in mm/dd/yyyy format. I want to change it in dd/mm/yyyy format.

In image you can see Planned Date in American format which I want to change

[image]

Comment: Try this - {{ editVersionCtrl.selectedPlannedDate | date : 'dd/mm/yyyy' }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use filter to achieve this

check this [Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aBxpMg) out

as @sanjay Achar suggested you could try the below code

```
<md-datepicker
  ng-model="editVersionCtrl.selectedPlannedDate"
  ng-change="editVersionCtrl.checkPlannedDate()">

  {{selectedPlannedDate | date: 'dd/mm/yyyy'}}
</md-datepicker>
```

Comment: Worked for me.Thanks. I have to include Moment.js

Answer (score 0):

Use date filter of angular but remember the date must be a timestamp. Convert it to timestamp and apply filter like

```
<span>{{'1288323623006' | date:"dd/MM/yyyy"}}</span><br>
```

Comment: <md-datepicker ng-model="editVersionCtrl.selectedPlannedDate" ng-change="editVersionCtrl.checkPlannedDate()" >
                                {{editVersionCtrl.selectedPlannedDate|date:"dd/MM/yyyy 'at' h:mma"}}
                            </md-datepicker>

Comment: Something like this?

Comment: Can please tell me value of `editVersionCtrl.selectedPlannedDate`?